# null pointer exception despite having default values for my jetpack datastore

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-datastore

i'm trying to retrieve data store object that's giving me null values despite having default values

this is the get data function

```
override suspend fun getSettings(): Flow<Settings> = context.dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            if (exception is IOException) {
                Log.e("exception", "error reading preferences: $exception")
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            }
            else {
                throw exception
            }
        }
        .map { settings ->

            Settings(
                focusDur = settings[FOCUS_SLIDER] ?: 3.404918F,
                restDur = settings[BREAK_SLIDER] ?: 1.447541F,
                longRestDur = settings[LONG_SLIDER] ?: 1.909836F,
                rounds = settings[ROUND_SLIDER] ?: 2f
            )
        }
```

i have default values as elvis operator for all the variables in my data object

and here is my viewmodel.

```
@HiltViewModel
class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val settingsManager: SettingsManager
) : ViewModel() {

     var settings : MutableLiveData<Settings> = MutableLiveData()


        fun retrieveDate() {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                settingsManager.getSettings().collect {
                    settings.postValue(it)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and in my ui i get the settings like

```
var settings = viewModel.settings.value
```

and when i assign the value like

```
var noOfRoundsSliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(settings.rounds) }
```

im getting null pointer exception

settings is nullable even when i try to use .let or !! i get null values
my question is how can get the default value that i set in getsettings function ?